# URL forwarding for Lambda functions within VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

My AWS lambda function code is calling an external API says *GET* method *example.com/getBooks*
That lambda function is deployed using AWS SAM and running within VPC & Subnets.

What I am trying to achieve is to redirect the *example.com/getBooks* to my API Gateway URL(eg. xxxyy.us-east-2.com/getBooks) without modifying lambda code and without needing to create environment parameter for lambda function.

It wasn't as easy as I thought like what I usually done in Windows/Linux by just adding the mapping source and destination URL to the hosts file.

I am not getting relevant solution after reading and testing thru Route 53, Route Tables and AWS ELB
I have setup Route 53 resolver but it doesn't let me put my expected target FQDN, instead it is asking for IP address.

Anyone can suggest a solution for this.
Appreciate for help.

Comment: You really can't do this without modifying the Lambda function. It would be trivial to change an environment variable for the Lambda function, versus all the work you are trying to do to override how DNS works inside the VPC.

Comment: Hi @MarkB, Thannks for confirming that, adding environment variable and changing lambda code is last resort to me because I am looking for changes in network configuration instead of touching the code.